# Does matching with argThat only work for methods with a single argument?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I have the following method invocation in my class under test:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
   [...]
    restTemplate.getForEntity(url, MyResponseEntity.class, parameterMap);
   [...]
}
```

In the unit test of the class containing this line, I want to stub the `getForEntity` method such that it returns different responses for different entries in the `parameterMap`.
Using BDDMockito, I'm trying to match that the desired parameter is part of the parameterMap by using [`argThat`](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#argThat%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29):

```
@InjectMocks
private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

[...]

given(restTemplate.getForEntity(anyString(), any(Class.class), argThat(hasEntry("myKey", "myValue"))
   .willReturn(responseEntityA);
```

However, if I run the test such that the `parameterMap` contains (I verified this in the debugger) a key "myKey" and a value "myValue", I get a `NullPointerException`, because mockito does not seem to be able to match the method call with the stub I created.

On the other hand, using the following very general matching allows me run my tests without NPE, by providing a default response for *all* calls, however it does not allow me to define a custom response for a given parameter.

```
given(restTemplate.getForEntity(anyString(), any(Class.class), anyMap())
  .willReturn(defaultResponseEntity);
```

What is the reason for this? Does `argThat` only work for methods with a single parameter?
Is there another way to match calls of the `getEntity` with a map that contains a certain (key, value) pair?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?  Unfortunately, it seems to handle method overloading with varargs and generics slightly differently from Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argThat` certainly works for more than one parameter, and there's nothing obviously wrong with what you're trying to do. I have a nagging hunch that it's selecting [the wrong overload](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-):

```
getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String,?> urlVariables)
getForEntity(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... urlVariables)
```

If the generics don't exactly match, Java may assume that your `hasEntry` best matches the `Object...` method where your `anyMap` matched the `Map<String, ?>`. In that case, you would be stubbing an overload you're not calling (`Object...`), and Mockito would revert to default return values for the one you're actually calling in your system under test (`Map<String, ?>`). Hovering over the method call in your IDE may shed light on which overload the compiler is matching.

To give Java a better hint, try a cast, which would look like this (warning, not tested or verified):

```
given(restTemplate.getForEntity(
         anyString(),
         any(Class.class),
         (Map<String, ?>) argThat(hasEntry("myKey", "myValue"))))
    .willReturn(responseEntityA);
```

Comment: this indeed helped, thanks! the matching is now working as expected.

Comment: + you actually answered the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the `argThat` is not working for you but you could try using `thenAnswer` and checking the arguments in your `Answer`.

Comment: -1 for a viable work-around? Wow, tough crowd. +1 since sometimes you have to zig instead of zag.